# Right to Left Resize Animation

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I want to Resize View with animation Right to Left, from X to 0, now I've created this class:

```
public class ResizeAnimationRightToLeft extends Animation {

    private View mView;
    private float mToHeight;
    private float mFromHeight;

    private float mToWidth;
    private float mFromWidth;

    public ResizeAnimationRightToLeft(View v, float fromWidth, float fromHeight, float toWidth, float toHeight) {
        mToHeight = toHeight;
        mToWidth = toWidth;
        mFromHeight = fromHeight;
        mFromWidth = fromWidth;
        mView = v;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        float height =
                (mToHeight - mFromHeight) * interpolatedTime + mFromHeight;
        float width = (mToWidth - mFromWidth) * interpolatedTime + mFromWidth;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = mView.getLayoutParams();
        p.height = (int) height;
        p.width = (int) width;
        mView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Than I use:

```
ResizeAnimationRightToLeft scale = 
    new ResizeAnimationRightToLeft(layout, 0, DIM_HEIGHT, DIM_WIDTH, DIM_HEIGHT);
```

But this resize view from Left to Right, now I don't understand how to reverse this, could someone show me the way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved with this:

```
ScaleAnimation animationRightToLeft = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
animationRightToLeft.setDuration(200);

ScaleAnimation animationLeftToRight = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
animationLeftToRight.setDuration(200);
```